# materialized view vs procedure in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My source table is being updated in every 5 min what is best option materialized view vs procedure in snowflake

1. Create materialized view and refresh in every 5 min.
2. Create procedure and schedule in task that will run in every 5 min.

if something goes wrong while refreshing materialized view then how to track the error? error tracking is easy inside the procedure.

Which one is better (materialized view or procedure/task)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at pros and cons of each implementation and of course cost.

**Materislised View**

- great for a source that does **not** change often
- also good for accessing content that may be of a different clustering to the source table
- does have a storage cost
- does have a serverless compute cost associated with it for maintaining the MV
- is limited to a single table source, no joins and has other restrictions in terms of available functions

**Stored Proc**

- unexecuted code
- no storage cost
- can suite complex joins and functions
- will be slower than an MV because it needs to execute code
- if needed to run periodically, can be combined with tasks, or better yet, streams and tasks if dealing with deltas.
- the same stored proc run twice without any of the underlying data changing could take advantage of Snowflake's caching
- running a task is not free, goes into cloud services charges. But as long as the CS charges are less than 10% of the daily compute charge it could be free.

Comprehensive guide: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html

Comment: incase of error while refreshing the Materialized View, how can we track the error, but same we can do in snowflake stored procedure. please suggest.

Comment: An MV wouldn't give you an error, unless you failed to comply with the MV definition rules.

For an SP however, if you pass all the syntactical rules then the errors can be defined by you, through error trapping routine code using JavaScript.

Enclosing commands in TRY {} and other error handling routines: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#javascript-error-handling

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html#limitations-on-creating-materialized-views

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake, Materialized Views are maintained automatically, so it does not need to be refreshed manually, and they will always provide up to date data.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html#advantages-of-materialized-views

As I understand, as an alternative to MV, you are planning to create a stored procedure and task to build a summary table by yourself, and refresh it periodically.

If this is the case, I highly recommend you to use the Materialized View, so you don't need to deal with the maintenance of the procedure/summary table, and you always get up to date data from the MV.

Answer (score 0):

Also.. currently Materialized Views have a number of restrictions. Like no JOINS :(